grub-pc not working after install and configured using preseed
I have a custom installer that installs ubuntu 22.04 and want to make it unattended/automatic - preconfiguring all the packages before hand so that the user shouldn't have to do anything other than remove the USB drive at the end.
After the installer has completed the system power-cycles into a blank screen with a flashing cursor.
Booting into a Ubuntu Live cd, mounting the installed partitions and installing grub using grub-install /dev/sda solves the issue.
Currently using the following grub-pc preseed configurations:
grub-pc grub-pc/timeout string  2
grub-pc grub-pc/install_devices_failed_upgrade  boolean true
grub-pc grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline  string  
grub-pc grub2/device_map_regenerated    note    
grub-pc grub-pc/postrm_purge_boot_grub  boolean false
grub-pc grub-pc/chainload_from_menu.lst boolean true
grub-pc grub2/linux_cmdline_default string  quiet splash
grub-pc grub-pc/install_devices multiselect /dev/sda

After installation on a live ubuntu CD before running grub-install in chroot we can see the configurations have been set:
root@ubuntu:/# debconf-show grub-pc
* grub-pc/install_devices_failed_upgrade: true
  grub2/unsigned_kernels_title:
  grub-efi/install_devices_failed: false
  grub-pc/mixed_legacy_and_grub2: true
  grub2/unsigned_kernels:
  grub-pc/kopt_extracted: false
  grub2/update_nvram: true
* grub-pc/chainload_from_menu.lst: true
  grub-pc/install_devices_disks_changed:
* grub2/device_map_regenerated:
  grub-efi/partition_description:
* grub-pc/timeout: 2
  grub2/no_efi_extra_removable: false
* grub-pc/postrm_purge_boot_grub: false
  grub-efi/install_devices:
  grub-pc/disk_description:
* grub-pc/install_devices: /dev/sda
  grub-efi/install_devices_disks_changed:
* grub2/linux_cmdline_default: quiet splash
* grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline:
  grub-pc/hidden_timeout: true
  grub-pc/install_devices_empty: false
  grub-efi/install_devices_empty: false
  grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline_default: quiet splash
* grub2/linux_cmdline:
  grub-pc/partition_description:
  grub-pc/install_devices_failed: false

After manually running grub-install and booting into the system and trying to reconfigure grub using dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc all of the values from the configuration are preselected as set by pre-seed apart from
GRUB install devices:
Manually selecting dev/sda and rerunning debconf-show grub-pc the value for grub-pc/install_devices changes to /dev/disk/by-id/<SOME-DISK-ID...>
So I am wondering, why is my grub not being configured after installation despite all configurations being present
Is there a more generic way to preselect the install_devices that doesn't involve a unique ID?
